# Error installing json 1.8.3 with ruby 2.4

Tags: ruby

[version information]

ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
/   gem 2.0.3 / 
Windows 10

I ran `bundle install` and it told me to run `gem install json -v '1.8.3'`

I did that and got a *Failed to build gem native extension* error.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
generator.c: In function ‘generate_json’:
generator.c:861:25: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                         ^
generator.c:861:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
generator.c:863:25: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                         ^
generator.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare" [enabled by default]
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

I've checked several documents.
I installed Devkit and json 1.8.5 but my project keeps the message that "install json 1.8.3"
How can I solve this problem??

`/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3` contains:

```
../
./
data/
diagrams/
ext/
java/
lib/
tests/
tools/
install.rb*
.gitignore
.travis.yml
CHANGES
COPYING
COPYING-json-jruby
GPL
Gemfile
README-json-jruby.markdown
README.rdoc
Rakefile
```

`/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out` contains:

```
user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
generator.c: In function ‘generate_json’:
generator.c:861:25: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                         ^
generator.c:861:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
generator.c:863:25: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                         ^
generator.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare" [enabled by default]
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
```

Comment: The first question is why do you need the JSON gem? Ruby has JSON support built-in. Secondly, why use an older version? Ruby 2.4.0 changed a number of internals that may necessitate using the latest version of that gem. If you're stuck with a hard dependency on this particular version you may need to use Ruby 2.3.x or something that it can compile against until you can get that restriction removed.

Comment: @tadman I need the JSON version 1.8.3 because putty require me to. If I run `bundle install`, putty order me to set up JSON 1.8.3. I installed other versions (2.0.3 and 2.0.2) but it keeps saying "install JSON 1.8.3".. Actually I am a beginner and just following guideline I have, so I am not flexible in dealing with problems.

Comment: @tadman Ruby 2.6.5 also has same issue. In my case, JSON is a req. gem of ActiveSupport. Installing v 1.8.5 solved the issue (v1.8.4 don't exists)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I ran into the same issue recently as well, try and see if there's a newer version of whatever gem you're using that depends on json 1.8.3. This is happening because Ruby 2.4 unified [Fixnum and Bignum into Integer](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12005). If you're able to upgrade to [json 1.8.5](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/311) or higher, it should help fix your problems.

You could also try and update the gem you're using and try to relax the version constraints (I've found this to work with a lot of projects, but not all) like so:

```
gem 'json', '>= 1.8'
```

Comment: I tried to install newer version of gem but it gave me this error.

Comment: undefined method `source_paths' for #<Gem::Specification:0x145dc28 rubygems-update-2.6.10>

Comment: @김혜진 That's a new problem, so at least you're getting somewhere. Usually that's an issue with something interacting with Rubygems and expecting to be an older version.

Comment: I downgraded ruby version and this JSON error have gone. Thank you for your help!

Comment: in my case, just update to the latest (i.e. 2.5.1)

Answer (score 35):

Try removing the Gemfile.lock and running the bundle command again. It should be using a different version of json (ie. 1.8.6) without a problem.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You shouldn't be forced to pollute your Gemfile with `gem 'json', '>= 1.8'` if you are not explicitly requiring it.  When you delete the Gemfile.lock, you allow bundler to build a new dependency tree and find try to resolve the incompatibility.

Comment: Just run `bundle update json` if you only want to update that gem but keep the rest of your gems locked to the versions they are in your `Gemfile.lock`. This worked for me.

Comment: install json 1.8.6 works for me under ruby 2.4  ,  thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

In Gemfile.lock

```
json (~>1.8.3)
```

then do the

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

I forced the installation of json 1.8.5 and changed the entry in Gemfile.lock, seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

I performed the following steps: insert the above command in gemfile (gem 'json', '>= 1.8') and with event of error in run bundle install I was realized bundle update and installed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the line starting with "json" in Gemfile.lock with the following the line

`json (~>1.8.3)`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me.

> ```
>    1.)  gem install json_pure
>    2.)    rvm list
>           ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
>        =* ruby-2.7.1 [ x86_64 ]
>    3.) rvm use 2.1.5
>    4.) bundle install
> ```

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem. Feasible solution is we should first remove the json from gem

```
"gem uninstall json"
```

and then 
install

```
"sudo bundle install"
```

> Don't forget to add sudo. Without sudo it will fail to install.

Comment: `Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.`